# Why is the Python CSV reader ignoring double-quoted fields?

Tags: python, csv

I think this is probably something simple, but after an hour of searching, I've had no luck figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using the following code to read a CSV file - I have no problem reading the file, but when a line contains a field that is double-quoted because it contains the delimiter, the CSV reader ignores the double-quotes and parses the field into 2 separate fields.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
myReader = csv.reader(open(inPath, 'r'), dialect='excel', delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for row in myReader:
    print row,
    print len(row)
```

My input:

```
hello, this is row 1, foo1
hello, this is row 2, foo2
goodbye, "this, is row 3", foo3
```

Which gives me:

```
['hello', ' this is row 1', ' foo1'] 3
['hello', ' this is row 2', ' foo2'] 3
['goodbye', ' "this', ' is row 3"', ' foo3'] 4
```

What do I need to change so it will recognize the double-quoted field as one field?
I'm using python version 2.6.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you look at the dialect that you're using, you'll notice that the excel dialect is
configured as follows:

```
class excel(Dialect):
    """Describe the usual properties of Excel-generated CSV files."""
    delimiter = ','
    quotechar = '"'
    doublequote = True
    skipinitialspace = False
    lineterminator = '\r\n'
    quoting = QUOTE_MINIMAL
```

Notice that `skipinitialspace` is set to False. Just pass that into your reader.
Oh and by the way, all the fields you've passed in are already the defaults when
using the `excel` dialect, which is the default dialect parameter passed to [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

So, I would re-write your code like so:

```
>>> with open(inPath) as fp:
>>>     reader = csv.reader(fp, skipinitialspace=True)
>>>     for row in reader:
>>>         print row,
>>>         print len(row)
['hello', 'this is row 1', 'foo1'] 3
['hello', 'this is row 2', 'foo2'] 3
['goodbye', 'this, is row 3', 'foo3'] 3
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because your csv has spaces before the quotes:

```
one0, one1, one2
two0, two1, two2
tre0, "tr,e1", tre2
```

vs

```
one0,one1,one2
two0,two1,two2
tre0,"tr,e1",tre2
```

You'll need to remove those extra spaces first.

Comment: That's wrong: `csv.reader()` has the `skipinitialspace` option to deal with those blanks.