# Python CSV module, special split string

Tags: python, string, csv

i had an unique problem.
I have code:

```
with open("test.csv", "r") as csvFile:
reader = csv.reader(csvFile, skipinitialspace=True)
for row in reader:
    for obj in row:
        print(obj)
```

and exemplary csv file:

```
anotherCommand, e=5, f=6, g=7, h=9, test="aaa, bbb, ggggg"
```

i want split this string in this way:

```
anotherCommand
e=5
f=6
g=7
h=9
test="aaa, bbb, ggggg"
```

but code which i was presented, split these string in this way:

```
anotherCommand
e=5
f=6
g=7
h=9
test="aaa
bbb
ggggg"
```

This is wrong solution this problem.
I saw topic like:
[Why is the Python CSV reader ignoring double-quoted fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879596/why-is-the-python-csv-reader-ignoring-double-quoted-fields)
or
[How can i parse a comma delimited string into a list (caveat)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118096/how-can-i-parse-a-comma-delimited-string-into-a-list-caveat/118187#118187)

But this example is different, and these examples not come up my expectation.
Someone have idea?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ doesn't work, the same situation like in linked sites :)

Comment: Can you please add some details? What exactly did you do, that didn't work.

Comment: i wrote: with open("test.csv", "r") as csvFile:
    for line in csv.reader(csvFile, quotechar='"', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True):
        print(len(line))   ---- and i still get the same values like presented in my main answer

Comment: i model my code on answer which You linked :)

Comment: should i use regex? If yes, did someone could give me a few directions to solution?

Comment: Where is the difference with the first one you linked to?

Comment: @Robert is `anotherCommand, e=5, f=6, g=7, h=9, test="aaa, bbb, ggggg"`  an example of a *raw* row in your CSV file?

Comment: @zezollo in first link, there is a pure string, i mean: 56, "some, pure, str" ---- in my case, i have: key="some, pure, string". Understand?

Comment: @JonClements Yes

Comment: @JonClements real example, which i must process: queue, name="EQ_L2_PS_PEER_0, ESP, ON", id=0x1007, qgroup_addr=0x31f597c0

Comment: Are they all in that format? eg: one column of something, then following columns of key=value or key="value" ?

Comment: no, other row example in my csv file: msg, type=0x0000000000000000, id=0x0304, dst=0x00001003

Comment: @RobertPawlak OK, I get it

Comment: Key to your problem is that your "csv" isn't a well-formed CSV file. If you can generate it so it is valid then python csv parsing will work. Seems like for your example you need to add quotes around the test="aaa, bbb, ggggg" so it looks like "test="aaa, bbb, ggggg"", but you might get away with simply adding quotes around every value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly make use of `shlex.split` here:

```
import shlex

with open('test.csv') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        row = [col.rstrip(',') for col in shlex.split(line)]
        print(*row, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Great man! Works! Could You explain me more Your solution? Or link sites, that should i visit to learn?

Comment: This is a advantage I planed delete them in further file process

Comment: @Robert as to references - have a look at the documentation for the `shlex` module - it tries to parse text as a shell would when passing command line arguments to a program... (which is what your lines looked more like to me than actual CSV data - so just thought I'd give it a go and see if it produced something workable with for your use case and it mostly did minus retaining trailing commas - hence the `str.rsplit` there)...

Comment: this is an output with different format, which was designed on csv.

Comment: @Robert Might make sense if you do a `values = dict(col.partition('=')[::2] for col in row)` to get a `dict` of key/values to use if that's applicable for what you want to use it for...

Comment: @Robert then you get something like: `{'id': '0x1007', 'name': 'EQ_L2_PS_PEER_0, ESP, ON', 'qgroup_addr': '0x31f597c0', 'queue': ''}` - so if the first column is always straight text with key=value, then maybe ignore that, but otherwise, might be a more useful structure...